# Details about KNN based background segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, research

I build a python script which uses OpenCV implementation of KNN Backgroud Segmentation/Remover.

I know the basics of how KNN works, but not how the background segmentation works.
For the MOG algorithm I found lots of papers, but I havn't found a single one for KNN background segmentation. Apart from wanting to understand the algorithm better, I also need a good source for my project citations.

Even the linked sources in the OpenCV [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d88/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorKNN.html#details) are wrong, they are linking to the MOG source. (Zoran Zivkovic and Ferdinand van der Heijden. Efficient adaptive density estimation per image pixel for the task of background subtraction.)

Has anyone a good source on this?